# Почему невидимый объект после на карте имеет значение isShown == true?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я создаю карту с данными настройками и заполняю объектами через objectManager (далее код упрощён для читабельности):

```
new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    viewportMargin: 0,
    gridSize: 64,
});
...
new ymaps.Map('outpost-map', {
    center: ['61.698653', '99.505405'],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: ['zoomControl'],
    margin: 0,
})
...
```

При событии карты `boundschange` я хочу проверить, показан ли объект на карте, если нет, то добавить его id в новый список. В список попадают много объектов, которые НЕ отображены зрительно на карте:

```
objectManager.objects.each(function (object) {
    objectManager.getObjectState(object.id);

    if (objectState.isShown) {
        my_list.push(object.id);
    }
});
```

Все слои имеют ширины\высоту как у div'a карты, кроме canvas внутри `ymaps-2-1-77-ground-pane`, и, как следствие `ymaps-2-1-77-placemark-overlay` имеет позицию где-то за пределами div'a, но на canvas.

Как это исправить, чтобы все размеры подложек соответствовали родительскому div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему `margin: 0, viewportMargin: 0` надо было присвоить объектам, а не карте\менеджеру.
В массив `'features': []`:

```
    ...
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [item.point_lat, item.point_lon],
        viewportMargin: 0,
        margin: 0,
    },
    ...
```

Из блоков `new ymaps.Map` и `new ymaps.ObjectManager` можно удалить `margin: 0, viewportMargin: 0`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/526484)

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос и я и есть автор так-то.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос это то, что понятно не только Вам. Покажите код как было и как правильно в ответе, тогда это будет информация, полезная другим участникам сообщества.